# How to use fscanf to read lines separated by semicolon

Tags: c, scanf

For example, I am trying to get the total age from a text file separated by semicolons with the format of `Name;Age;Favorite Number`

```
Jack;12;3
Red;21;15
Blue;14;6
```

I have tried doing something like this.

```
File *fp;
fp = fopen(in_file,"r");
int sum = 0, age = 0, fav_number = 0;
while (fscanf(fp,"%c %f %f", name, age, fav_number) != EOF) {
    fscanf(fp, "%c %f %f", name, age, fav_number);
    sum += age;
}
```

But since it is not separated with space by with semicolon, it wouldn't work. I am not sure how to change it. Any clue on how to do it?

Comment: Check the meaning of `"%c"`.

Comment: Compare to e.g.  `"%[^;]"`.

Comment: Do you know that you have several other problems? Does your code compile? Do you get warnings? Strict warnings? Which?

Comment: Yea should use "%s"

Comment: No. That will give you the whole line.

Comment: Yea, wasn't so sure on how to do it so I haven't yet compiled the program, but should have.

Comment: Please study the concept of making a [MCVE]. Compilability is the minimum condition (at least for runtime problems). Do not ask questions before doing some experiments yourself.

Comment: oh my bad. so something like "%s%[^;]" ?

Comment: Try yourself. Please. And if you find out that it reads all of the line into `name` then read my comment 4 minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues with your code. Firstly its recommended to check the return value of `fopen()` for e.g this

```
fp = fopen(in_file,"r");
```

should be

```
fp = fopen(in_file,"r");
if(fp == NULL) {
   /* error handling @TODO */
}
```

Secondly, the `fscanf()` arguments are not correct, surely compiler produces the warnings but seems you ignored them.  This

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%c %f %f", &name, &age, &fav_number) != EOF) { /* read the name from file & store into name i.e it should be &name if name is char variable */
      fscanf(fp,"%c %f %f", &name, &age, &fav_number);
      sum += age;
}
```

lastly if you want to read the lines separated by semicolon then use `%[^;]` or use `strtok()`. Or it's better to read whole line first using `fgets()` and then use `strtok()`. To know how `strtok()` works read the manual page [strtok](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html).

Comment: Thanks. So should it be something like this?

Comment: fscanf(fp,"%c %[^;] %f %[^;] %f %[^;] ,&name, &age, &fav_number);

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues in your code:

- `File` should be `FILE`
- you should test the return value of `fopen()`
- the format string for `fscanf()` is incorrect: `%c` reads just one character, `%f` requires a pointer to `float` and you instead provide an `int` value...
- you should compare the return value of `fscanf()` to the number of expected conversions (`3` in your code), not `EOF` which is only returned at end of file if no conversions were performed.
- you call `fscanf()` twice.

Since you are not interested in the `Name` and `Favorite colour` fields, you can just ignore them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char in_file[] = "test.csv";
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(in_file, "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        double sum = 0, age = 0;
        while (fscanf(fp," %*[^;];%lf;%*lf", &age) == 1) {
            sum += age;
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("total of ages: %g\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that it would be more reliable to read the input file one line at a time and parse it with `sscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[256];
    char in_file[] = "test.csv";
    double sum = 0, age = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(in_file, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input file %s\n", in_file);
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        if (sscanf(buf,"%*[^;];%lf;%*lf", &age) == 1) {
            sum += age;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid data: %s\n", buf);
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("total of ages: %g\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```